# How to add uikit to cclayer subclass in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

If I want to subclass a cclayer to add uikit elements, what is the
property where I need to add the views?

I think I cannot use [ccdirector shareddirector] openGLView

since its the main view, am I right?

Is there something like: self.view as a cclayer property?

Comment: [[[ccdirector shareddirector] openGLView] addSubView:<view>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add UIKit views either to the CCDirector view or the main window. You can't add UIKit views to cocos2d nodes (CCLayer etc.).

This also means that by default any UIKit view will be in front of the cocos2d view (in front of all cocos2d nodes).

You can not have cocos2d nodes in front of and behind cocos2d nodes if that's what you're asking. The UIKit views are either completely in front of everything cocos2d displays, or if setup correctly you can add UIKit views behind everything cocos2d displays. But you can't layer UIKit views in between cocos2d nodes/layers/sprites/etc.

Comment: thats what I was asking so I came to conclusion a standard uikit framework will be better for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

i think what you need is [CCUIViewWrapper](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889)

You basically init the UIKit thing normally and then add it as a CCNode. That CCNode can be added to any subclass of CCNode as a child.

Answer (score 0):

See this

Here is The Link For embedding The `UIKit` Element into The `Cocos2D` Code.

See You may get some Idea From Here [Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit)